# Play UDP stream in VLC?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming, udp

I receive an UDP video stream of which I know both the IP adresses and the incoming and outgoing ports of both computers. How can I play it in vlc?

```
udp:@:1234
```

Does not work for me. How to fix this?

Comment: No need for the '@' you only need that if you're doing multicast (are you doing multicast?), 'udp://0.0.0.0:1234' where '1234' is the outgoing port should work.  What format is your video?

Answer (score 15):

Use this syntax: `udp://@:1234`

However, it is also possible that VLC is interpreting the @ as listening on an IPv6 port instead of IPv4, in which case [this page](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/919) suggests that using `udp://@0.0.0.0:1234` may get it to listen on an IPv4 port.

Comment: I tried doing that. And I first mistyped the port and got nothing. Then I did it correctly and I got an error. This seems like I have no acces. Any idea?

Comment: Is the port num high enough (e.g. more than 10 000)?